# PODS With Polylang, translations are being duplicated / synchronised when translating a post

Tags: wordpress, translation, polylang

So, I’m using custom post types, all in PODS, and Polylang for translations. The thing is, when I try to translate one of the posts, all the content on the original post type is duplicated to the translated version.

For example, I have a field `game title` in the custom post type. The english version is “Great game”, then I translate it with the `+` of polylang, and add `Buen juego` for the spanish language. When I check back the english version, the english text changed back to `Buen juego` instead of remaining the original text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since the only help I found was on Slack support channel which won't be documented for posterity.

Basically Polylang has a `Synchronisation` setting, when it's turned on it synchronises the meta data of posts, but since PODS uses that data for the actual PODS system, Polylang will synchronize all the translations constantly.

Just disable that option if you're having this problem :)

`All Pods fields (and most field UI plugins) store the data in the meta table. So if you set them to synchronize it will constantly overwrite each other.
There is no option (yet) to select which metafields to sync in Polylang`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in:
Languages > Settings > Synchronization > Disable custom fields check